# Crystal Report in VS2008 doesn't display data on web

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I have a problem with my crystal reports in Visual Studio 2008, and after searching and searching I got nothing.

My file CrystalReportxxx.rpt has an xsd file as dataschema. A datatable is created and it's passed to report as datasource. To fill the datatable, my application connects to Oracle database.

For showing rows or data with CrystalReportViewer, the report needs credentials like logid and password of database. However, if I export this report to a PDF file, then no credentials are needed and PDF file shows all rows.

This is my code:

```
      Dim dt As DataTable 
        FunctionsOP.CreaDataTable("pkg_list.sp_list", True, ospEntry, 
dt) 
        Dim oRpt As New Reportes.CrystalReportxxx 
        oRpt.SetDatabaseLogon("userxxx", "passwordxxx") 
        oRpt.SetDataSource(dt) 
        CrystalReportViewer1.EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt = False
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = oRpt 
        CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind() 
        CrystalReportViewer1.Dispose()
```

I suppose that when setting: 
        oRpt.SetDatabaseLogon("userxxx", "passwordxxx") 
and report shows no data, is because credentials are wrong.

My question is: How to bypass this credential input?

**Is it mandatory to input userid, password, etc for using a xsd file in my Crystal 
Report?**

What is strange to me is that when I export that report to PDF, there is no 
problem. Data is shown OK and no credential is needed:

```
    Dim exportOpts As ExportOptions = oRpt.ExportOptions 
        oRpt.ExportOptions.ExportFormatType = 
ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat 
        oRpt.ExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = 
ExportDestinationType.DiskFile 
        oRpt.ExportOptions.DestinationOptions = New 
DiskFileDestinationOptions 
        CType(oRpt.ExportOptions.DestinationOptions, 
DiskFileDestinationOptions).DiskFileName = Server.MapPath("../Temp/" + 
PDFName) 
        oRpt.Export() 
        oRpt.Close() 
        oRpt.Dispose()
```

---

I also tried this code:

```
  Dim dt1 As New DataTable : Dim dt2 As New DataTable
    Dim oRpt As New Reportes.CR_IndicadorA11
    Dim ParRep As ReportClass = oRpt
    SetConnectionsReports(ParRep)
    FunctionsOP.CreaDataTable("pkg_Listar_Tipos.sp_indicador_a11_sum", True, Nothing, dt1)
    FunctionsOP.CreaDataTable("pkg_Listar_Tipos.sp_indicador_a11_det", True, Nothing, dt2)
    oRpt.SetDataSource(dt1)
    oRpt.OpenSubreport("CR_sub_indicadorA11_det.rpt").SetDataSource(dt2)

    CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = True
    CrystalReportViewer1.EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt = False
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = oRpt
    CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind()
    CrystalReportViewer1.Dispose()

    Public Sub SetConnectionsReports(ByRef Rpt As ReportClass)
            Dim server, base, user, pass As String

            server = "SRVBDDESA2.DOMINTERN0XXX.LOCAL" ' also with IP number is the same

            base = "DESAOPINT"
            user = "ORGPOL"
            pass = "desarrollo"

            For Each connection As IConnectionInfo In Rpt.DataSourceConnections
                connection.SetConnection(server, base, user, pass)
            Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried to set setLogon information for each table involved

Comment: Yes, and no success. Is not there a way to set up Crystal Report or CrystalReportViewer for not asking credentials?

Why credentials are not asked when report is exported to PDF?